# Command to drop all columns in a database that have prefix test_ to run

Tags: mysql

How I can run a command in phpMyAdmin which will drop all columns in a database that have the prefix `test_`.

Comment: You're not using the correct terminology which makes it unclear what you want to do. Do you want to erase all records from tables starting with "test_" or do you really want to erase *columns* (fields). The last one is what you are asking but it does not make sense.

Comment: I want to delete columns starting with the prefix "test_" is this not possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To drop a column from a table, use the syntax:

```
alter table <tablename> drop column <columnname>
```

To find all the columns in a table in a database that start with test_, do the following:

```
select column_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where table_name = <table_name> and
      table_schema = <schema_name> and
      left(column_name, 5) = 'test_'  -- not using "like" because '_' is a wildcard char
```

If you were doing this manually, I would recommend running the following query and then pasting the results in to a mysql query interface:

```
select concat('alter table ', table_name, ' drop column ', column_name)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where table_name = <table_name> and
      schema_name = <schema_name> and
      left(column_name, 5) = 'test_'
```

You can do something similar in code, by running the query, returning the results and then running each row as a query.

Comment: Thanks but is there any way I could do this in bulk, like drop the column from all tables in the database that have the prefix test_ rather than just dropping columns from one specific table? Many thanks.

Comment: In this solution, you would just remove the "table_name = <table_name>" portion.  Multiple commands will be returned.  Just paste them all in.  Or, you can also use @eggyal's solution, with a cursor going over the table and using a prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! His was a great answer too but I found yours easier to understand since I'm a noob at MySQL haha :p so thank you :)

Comment: Nice approach! :) Note that it seems to be named "table_schema" instead of "schema_name".

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to *drop* the columns from your schema, you will need to generate the necessary SQL commands dynamically from MySQL's [information schema tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-schema.html).  Whilst it is possible to do that within a MySQL stored procedure using [SQL prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), which I demonstrate below, you may well find it easier to implement/understand in your preferred development language (which you do not mention in your question):

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE dropMatchingColumns(IN pattern VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT   CONCAT(
                 'ALTER TABLE `', REPLACE( TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '` ',
               GROUP_CONCAT(
                 'DROP COLUMN `', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
               )
             )
    FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE    COLUMN_NAME LIKE pattern AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
    GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
  ;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO @sql;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

With this procedure defined, one need only `CALL dropMatchingColumns('test\_%');` in order to drop all the columns prefixed with `test_` from the current database.

Answer (score 2):

If you have MySQl Workbench then you can delete multiple columns by simply do a mass selection and telling workbench to do a mass deletion of the selected columns

Answer (score 1):

I would like to explain or simplify this answer for those like me who were having trouble with this.

I was having trouble dropping a column with the name 'seq' in all tables in my database 'demo'.

You can create a selection with the commands formatted for each table using something like this:

```
Select concat('alter table ', table_name, ' drop column ', 'seq;')
from (select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
where table_name = table_name and
table_schema = 'demo') as t
```

This creates the alter table command for each table in the 'demo' database.

You have to select the result, copy it, and paste it back into the query editor.

It's a two step process, but if you have to do this several times, save the commands in a text file to run again later.