# How to drop all columns with the same name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database 'demo' where each table in the database has a column 'seq'.

Is there a way to drop the column 'seq' from every table in the 'demo' database?

I was trying to modify the code in [MYSQL command to drop all columns in a database that have prefix test_ to run in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133608/mysql-command-to-drop-all-columns-in-a-database-that-have-prefix-test-to-run-in) but getting stuck.

I was able to generate all the table names using:

```
select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
where table_name = table_name and
table_schema = 'demo'
```

and trying to work from here.

Comment: Can't you just make an SQL file where you copy-paste `ALTER TABLE tbl_1 DROP COLUMN seq` with the table name changed? How many tables do you have?

Comment: `alter table <tablename> drop column <columnname>`

Comment: I have 61 tables. It's not that I can't do it manually, but that I will have to do this on multiple occasions and was hoping to automate the process.