# mysql, how to drop tables that the table name starts with digits

Tags: mysql

I have 1200 tables in my database, and the table names of half of them are start with digits, just looks like this

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;

    1000_quarterly_1000
    1001_quarterly_1001
    ...
    quarterly_1000
    quarterly_1001
    ....
```

And I want drop all the tables the name of which start with digits, for example table `1000_quarterly_1000` must be dropped. And since tables have been dropped from the current database and I want to store them to other database I have defined.

How can I write `mysql query` to do this, since I can use `Python` to do this, but `mysql query` can be better.

Comment: In your query, use quotes

Comment: see [mysql-command-to-drop-all-columns-in-a-database-that-have-prefix-test-to-run-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133608/mysql-command-to-drop-all-columns-in-a-database-that-have-prefix-test-to-run-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to drop the tables in one statement, you can construct the statement as:

```
select concat('drop table ', group_concat(t.table_schema, '.', t.table_name separator ', '))
from information_schema.tables
where left(t.table_name, 1) between '0' and '9';
```

You can then try to execute a command:

```
declare @sql varchar(65000);

select @sql := concat('drop table ', group_concat(t.table_schema, '.', t.table_name separator ', '))
from information_schema.tables
where left(t.table_name, 1) between '0' and '9';

prepare s from @sql;

execute s;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat('drop table ',t.table_schema,'.',t.table_name,';') drop_ddl 
from information_schema.tables t where t.table_name rlike '[0-9].'
```